# Need help installing MooseX::Declare

Tags: perl, moose

I am running with Perl 5.10.1 installed using the package manager. I have successfully installed Moose from the CPAN shell, and I have tried to install the MooseX::Declare extention without success.. Here is what I have done:

```
$ sudo cpan > cpan.log
cpan[1]> install MooseX::Declare
```

> Cannot determine perl version info from lib/MooseX/Declare.pm
>
> Warning: prerequisite Devel::Declare 0.005011 not found.
>
> Warning: prerequisite MooseX::Method::Signatures 0.30 not found.

This is what appears in the terminal at first before the installation lauches, I have posted the 'cpan.log' file [here](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/48431).

Now, I have tried installing the two prereqs above, the latter depends on the first one. But installing the first one gives me this:

> cpan[6]> install Devel::Declare
>
> Running install for module 'Devel::Declare'
>
> Running make for F/FL/FLORA/Devel-Declare-0.006000.tar.gz
>
> Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/jfb/.cpan/build/Devel-Declare-0.006000-6qeuWN
>
> '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site' returned status 512, won't make
>
> Running make test
>
> Make had some problems, won't test
>
> Running make install
>
> Make had some problems, won't install

Comment: What output did you get from `install MooseX::Declare`?  1. were there test or installation failures? 2. what was the path that the cpan client printed for installing the library?  (Incidentally, there is MooseX package, so typing `install MooseX` should give you an error.)

Comment: do you get any output from your cpan install commands?

Comment: I have edited my question, this is what I obtain from the compilation of 'install MooseX::Declare'

Comment: Are you sure that everything else before MooseX::Declare installed properly? e.g. the dependencies that MooseX::Declare depends on? Can you post the entire install log (you can use http://paste.scsys.co.uk with channel #moose-dev selected) so we can figure out the root problem here?

Comment: (Make that the #moose channel, #moose-dev doesn't have its own pastebin.  But there is an issue that happened before MooseX::Declare, that isn't currently determinable by the information you have provided here.)

Comment: I posted it! Read the log here: http://paste.scsys.co.uk/48431

Comment: @Kaeso: there are a few issues here, e.g. the lack of any evidence of 'make test' being run on any of the dependencies, and YAML being missing.  I would suggest deleting /home/jfb/.cpan/build and starting over, installing YAML first -- generally when CPAN reports "Foo not installed, falling back to..." it is a hint to immediately install that missing module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, with good advice from **Ether**. What happened is that the YAML prerequesite was not installed/not installed properly. What I did is to start over by deleting the build folder and reinstalling:

```
$ sudo rm /home/jfb/.cpan/build -rf
$ sudo cpan > cpan.log
cpan[1]> install YAML
cpan[2]> install MooseX::Declare
```

Now everything seems to work, see the log file [here](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/48436).

Comment: Do not run `sudo cpan` because the tests will run with superuser privileges. This is a bad thing. Instead, setup [`make_install_make_command` and `mbuild_install_build_command`](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#Config_Variables) so the privileges are only elevated for the time when they are really needed: for installing into a system location.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that `MooseX::Declare` does not list the module named `aliased` as a dependency, while using it.  Try `install aliased` from the CPAN shell, then try installing `MooseX::Declare` again.

Comment: I've sent a pull request to the author to get the dependency list updated.  But FWIW, you almost certainly had some install failures before this point, as many other things require this module.

Comment: @Ether: How many is "many"?  Without doing any sort of comprehensive analysis, and just going by what I have installed on a couple of my boxes here ("a lot"), I can see a bunch of Catalyst modules, as well as `MooseX-Role-WithOverloading`, that's all.

Comment: Grrrr: some things MooseX::Declare depends on also depend on `aliased`, for example Parse::Method::Signatures and MooseX::Method::Signatures. I am hoping Kaeso sends his install logs.

Comment: vanilla CPAN.pm sometimes refuses to give up when it should, which means that one module fails, and then you get another three or four modules that depended on it also failing and cluttering up the log. Very frustrating.

Comment: I seem to have the aliased installed and updated allready:
cpan[2]> install aliased /
aliased is up to date (0.30).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems a few days ago, on OS X. In my case, either `MooseX::Method::Signatures` or `MooseX::Declare` depended on [B::Hooks::OP::Check](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/B-Hooks-OP-Check-0.18/lib/B/Hooks/OP/Check.pm). Once I installed that, all problems went away.

Comment: No I didn't. I attributed to problem to OS X, since I've never had any issues on Linux. But now, seeing this post, there might something to it, if course. I'd be helpful to know if the poster is also on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I had to force install Test::Pod before MooseX::Declare would install in a VM running rPath version 1.0.7 and Perl v5.8.7. After that, and after blowing away the CPAN build directory (per Kaeso's suggestion), MooseX::Declare installed without any problems.

I had installed Moose earlier and that went well.